# How can I improve a simple regression here?

Tags: regression, pca, factor-analysis, linear-model

I'm trying to solve the following issue :
Let's say that I have three normal random variables a,b,c, non correlated.

Let's say that I only have two observations of these, M and N where :

```
M = a + b
N = a + c
```

And another variable I'm trying to explain :

```
R = a + b + c + err
```

I can do a simple regression on this data, `lm(R ~ M + N + 0)`, I get the same loading for both `M` and `N`, equal to `0.66`.

My final model is `1.33a + 0.66b + 0.66c`.

I know that this model is the best linear model here, but what could I use to improve it. Are there methods to properly get `a, b, c` from `M`and `N` and do the regression on them ?

I've tried PCA but I only get two vectors, not three. Basically, I'd need a method that would project `M` and `N` into the three interesting components here.

**EDIT**

I realise I haven't been clear here.

$M$, $N$, $R$ are three vectors, with a high number of observations. If they had the relations above with three (unknown) factors $a$, $b$, $c$, then a simple regression would give me :
$\hat{R} = 0.66 M + 0.66 N = 1.33 a + 0.66 b + 0.66 c$.

I am wondering if there is an alternative technique for modelling $R$, that would give a closer result to the actual $R$. Something that would somehow reconstruct the common term $a$ from $M$ and $N$ automatically, and take that into account to finally get :
$\hat{R} = 1 a + 1 * (M - a) + 1 * (N - a)$

I hope I'm a bit more clear in my explanations ...

Comment: How do you do a regression when M is a single "observation" and N is a single observation?  Sure, it's mathematically possible, but it doesn't make sense to do so, so I wonder whether your data might actually differ from what this description seems to say.

Comment: If you have data for M, N, and R, and if err is small, don't you have a solvable situation of 3 equations and 3 unknowns (a, b, c)?

Comment: I try to re-word your question: - You have 3 observed vectors: $M$, $N$, and $R$. - You know that these are linear combinations of 4 unobserved quantities: $a$, $b$, $c$ and $err$, and that these are normally distributed and uncorrelated. You also know some of the weights: $$M =1 \cdot a + 1 \cdot b + 0 \cdot c + 0 \cdot err$$ $$N =1 \cdot a + 0 \cdot b + 1 \cdot c + 0 \cdot err$$ $$R = \beta_a \cdot a + \beta_b \cdot b + \beta_c \cdot c + 1 \cdot err$$ where $\beta$s are unkown. - You want to estimate $a$, $b$ and $c$. Is this what you say?

Comment: I think that OP has three latent factors and three observables which are linear combinations of these factors plus noise. The OP knows that noise is present only in the one of the observables, i.e the covariance matrix of the noise is singular. This makes it a factor analysis problem, although I think the problem is underdetermined.

Comment: Could you slap some dimensions on these? Your notation is really unclear. What do you mean when you say you get two vectors from PCA and not 3? What are you putting *in* to the PCA routine? What sort of estimate are you hoping to get out? The regression you give us might be the best unbiased estimate of R (for squared error), though again I suspect I'm not following your notation...